# Joomla CiviCRM add duplicate field in joomla front-end profile form

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, civicrm

Can any one say how to add duplicate field in joomla front-end profile form? I have to add two website field in the same form.

I am using joomla 2.5 and CiviCRM 4.3.4. I have configured front-end profile form and my task is almost completed. But one thing just blocked my way. I d I have searched a lot, but I could not get the answer. Can any one help me in this regard ?

Any help is appreciable.

I am also attaching the form screen shot.
[image: Form Screenshot.]

Answer (score 0):

CiviCRM does not support adding multiple website fields into a profile. You can add a custom field to the profile to hold an additional website. If you want to write a little code you can sync that to the website field with a hook. See [Hook Reference](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC43/Hook+Reference) as well as [Example Joomla Hook Plugin Setup](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC43/Example+Joomla+Plugin+for+implementing+hooks)